# Unable to upload file or create directory via Hadoop UI

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, webhdfs

I have installed hadoop-3.2.1 in Ubuntu 18.04 with Java-8. I am able to send files to HDFS using the `hadoop fs -put` command via terminal. But when I try to upload files or create a directory via UI, I am getting the following errors:

While Uploading a file :

> Couldn't upload the file temp.txt

While Creating a directory :

> Permission denied: user=dr.who, access=WRITE,
> inode="/":user1:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x

**hdfs-site.xml** file :

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>dfs.replication</name>
<value>1</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
<value>file:/usr/local/hadoop_tmp/hdfs/namenode</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
<value>file:/usr/local/hadoop_tmp/hdfs/datanode</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

Read about HDFS Permissions on [HDFS Permissions Guide](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsPermissionsGuide.html).

Temporarily, you can turn permissions completely off in `hdfs-site.xml`

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.permissions</name>
    <value>false</value>
</property>
```